# PHP strtotime(): date showing '1970-01-01 ' after conversion

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am reading the data from an excel sheet and inserting into MySQL table. In this process, I am converting the timestamp (string) to datetime using the PHP method `strtotime()`.

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:sa',strtotime(trim($value->Time)));
```

This is failing in some cases.

Example:

```
 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('04-13-2018 0:00:53'));

 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('04-12-2018 0:00:53'));
```

**Output:**

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00

2018-12-04 00:00:53
```

Can anyone help me how can I solve this issue?

Sample Strings for which it is failing:

```
04-12-2018 0:00:53
04-12-2018 0:01:53
04-12-2018 0:02:53
04-12-2018 0:03:53
04-12-2018 0:04:53
04-12-2018 0:05:53
04-12-2018 0:06:53
04-12-2018 0:07:53
04-12-2018 0:08:54
04-12-2018 0:09:54
04-12-2018 0:10:53
04-12-2018 0:11:53
04-12-2018 0:12:53
04-12-2018 0:13:53
04-12-2018 0:14:53
04-12-2018 0:15:53
04-12-2018 0:16:53
04-12-2018 0:17:53
04-12-2018 0:18:53
04-12-2018 0:19:54
04-12-2018 0:20:54
04-12-2018 0:21:54
04-12-2018 0:22:53
04-12-2018 0:23:54
04-12-2018 0:24:53
04-12-2018 0:25:54
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your format is not a [format that the parser understands](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

In your case `13` is not a "month". So the parser doesn't understand to date.

You should use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s','04-13-2018 0:00:53');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
2018-04-13 00:00:53
```

Note that the format could also be: `'m-d-Y G:i:s'` with `G` for *"24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros"*.

Comment: Got it. Just now, I figured it out and fixed it. Anyway, Thank you for your immediate response.

Comment: It's that you used a `-` to denote position, Php `strtotime()` parses that `-` as meaning `d-m-y`, and `m/d/y` is equivalent.

Comment: Also, @Syscall, if you look at the logic, the `13` is never meant to be a month. So that's nonsensical.

Comment: i know my format is not a valid format, but why function date('format',false) give me a date of 1970? why not returning false, or undefined?

Comment: @Andrea_86, as defined in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), the second parameter is an integer, so, your `false` value is interpreted as `0`. The date for the timestamp `0` is the unix timestamp (1970).

Comment: Thank you. and thank to the magic world where False are evaluated as 0 :)

Answer (score 2):

The string format is wrong for `strtotime()` and the (I don't recall the technical term) "American-formatted" value:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('04-13-2018 0:00:53'));
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('04/13/2018 0:00:53'));
```

https://3v4l.org/Qnsru

GIves:

```
1970-01-01 01:00:00
2018-04-13 00:00:53
```

Essentially, you gave `strtotime()` the (what's it called?) "European date time" value. It's the `-` that denotes the *day* is the first part, not *month*.

This bit me a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what has already been answered.
The reason you get 1970 is beacause [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns false if it can't parse the date.
And 0 (false) unix time is 1970.