# I want display my post time at jalali date php format

Tags: php, jalali-calendar

here is jdate library [jdate](https://jdf.scr.ir/source/)

my format.php file

```
<?php
/**
*Format Class
*/
class Format{
    public function formatDate($date){
        return date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($date));
    }

    public function textShorten($text, $limit = 400){
        $text = $text. "";
        $text = substr($text, 0, $limit);
        $text = substr($text, 0, strrpos($text, ' '));
        $text = $text. "";
        return $text;
    }
}
?>
```

and my post date code

```
<h6><?php echo $fm->formatDate($result['date']); ?>, by<a href="#"><?php echo $result['author']; ?></a></h6>
```

how can I use jdate instead of gregorian time .

Comment: _Small Point_ `$text = $text. "";` does nothing but use cpu cycles

Comment: _Second Small Point_ **No sensible SO user** is going to download unknown zip files in order to answer a question. The risk is just to high.. Please post code as text

Answer (score 1):

you should include the jdf.php file, then just use jdate instead of date

```
<?php
/**
*Format Class
*/
include_once('jdf.php');
class Format{
  public function formatDate($date){
     return jdate('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($date));
  }

  public function textShorten($text, $limit = 400){
    $text = $text. "";
    $text = substr($text, 0, $limit);
    $text = substr($text, 0, strrpos($text, ' '));
    $text = $text. "";
    return $text;
  }
}
?>
```

for more information and help, refer to [this link](https://jdf.scr.ir/rahnama/)

Comment: ali insert ur codes , but show wrong year-->1348 with this error Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\helpers\jdf.php on line 17

Comment: First comment: Does your date is in right format?  see this links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174713 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891937

Comment: 2nd comment : maybe you have forgot to include jdf.php in your index.php or maybe you have forgot to copy that file in the index directory

Comment: @Saeid, your welcome. so you can accept and/or vote up it. let me know , if the answer need to be edited.