# Datetime modify / format issue in PHP

Tags: php, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I have spent too many days & nights reading through documentation and trying just about anything to get this to work.

I have implemented this datetime picker for a website's contact form so users can make reservations and in turn the server will send an .ics calendar request to the owner for his records:
https://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/

The datetimepicker is configured via jquery.simple-dtpicker.js to have **format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm'** for both available languages, en & es for English and Spanish. The reason is the website is Spanish.

Up to here everything works great and I get a datetime value sent through when testing the contact form.

My issue is SIMPLY trying to add 1 hour to the obtained datetime in order to fulfill the required format for the .ics event in PHP.

Instead of adding an hour, it either defaults to the current local time and adds 1 hour or it defaults to 01/01/1970  (Epoch Time) and mangles the time. This is not the same outcome I get when succesfully testing the same code in online php testers.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
 $dateStart = $_POST['ical'];

 $date = date_format($dateStart, 'd-m-Y H:i');
 $dateZ = date('d-m-Y H:i', $date);
 $dateDone = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($dateStart + 3600));
 $date1 = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime('+1 hours', $dateStart));
 $date2 = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime('+1 hours', $dateZ));
 $date3 = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime('+1 hours', $date));
```

And my results:

```
$dateStart: 20-04-2021 05:00 
$dateDone:  09-04-3620 07:35 
$date1:     01-01-1970 02:00 
$date2:     01-01-1970 02:00 
$date3:     01-01-1970 02:00
```

Any idea what could be the issue? I cannot use any of the datetime format/modify/add functions which use -> operator for some reason so the only thing that seems to work is adding an hour via string or integer.

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP strtotime(): date showing '1970-01-01 ' after conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174713/php-strtotime-date-showing-1970-01-01-after-conversion)

Comment: I´m not sure.. does that mean that php cannot parse European formatted dates? How can I correctly add 1 hour to the $dateStart value?

Comment: See [Localized Notations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). Note that the 2nd parameter of [`strtotime()`](https://php.net/strtotime) need to be a timestamp, not a string.

Comment: The 2nd parameters are timestamps... the 1st parameters are the strings. I don´t see what you mean, the thing is I am not changing the date format anywhere, it comes from the datetimepicker in the required format already and it is an accepted format... the dates display correctly just not the correct values.

Comment: For example, in `strtotime('+1 hours', $dateZ)`, `$dateZ` is a string, not a timestamp.

Comment: What have you trried to debug the problem? Why not dump `strtotime('+1 hours', $dateStart)` to see what it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made very silly mistakes.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
$dateStart = '20-04-2021 05:00';

$date = date_format(new DateTime($dateStart), 'd-m-Y H:i'); // date_format need date time .. string were suplied

$dateZ = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($date));
$dateDone = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($dateStart + 3600)); // didnt get what exactly you need.. in date function you can add time easily using str to time
$date1 = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime('+1 hours'. $dateStart));
$date2 = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime('+1 hours'. $dateZ));
$date3 = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime('+1 hours'. $date));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Masih!! Now I am stuck trying to generate the .ics attachment to send via email so the recipient may add the event to their calendar... I can generate the content of the file just fine but have no clue how to correctly attach it to the email. I will create a new post for this. Regards!

Comment: I recommend you to use PHP mailer class for the same. there you can easily attach file. where else it is tricky to attach file in mail function header

Answer (score 2):

Using the classes DateTime, DateTimeZone and DateInterval

```
$dt = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo 'now: '.$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
$dt->add(new \DateInterval('PT1H'));
echo 'then : '.$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
```